# How to remap CSS shortcut key in Mac Bluefish text editor

Tags: css, macos

I am using Bluefish as a text editor for web development under Mac OSX. Whenever I attempt to type a word that begins with a capital S, Bluefish brings up the CSS Style Editor. Does anyone know how to solve this problem with Mac OS Bluefish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pinkpearl over on MacRumors for solving this problem. Everything beneath the line is copied from pinkpearl's posting.

---

I solved this problem. Close BlueFish and edit the file 
       ~/.bluefish/menudump_2.

Replace this line:

```
 ;(gtk_accel_path "<Actions> /htmlbarActions /DialogsCreateStyle" "<Shift> <Alt> s")

with:

  (gtk_accel_path "<Actions> /htmlbarActions /DialogsCreateStyle" "")
```

Save and open BlueFish. Now the shift+s writes S!